# fallo en redirección de http a https apache2 en ubuntu 16.04 en amazon EC2

Tags: apache, http, apache2, https, aws

Buenas os cuento estoy tratando de redirigir mi sito de http:// hacia https://
Me gustaria redirigirlo a través de apache pero no consigo hacer que funcione la redirección. 
Os cuento un poco la previa de lo que he hecho para ver si sirve de ayuda..

El virtual host es un EC2 de amazon. Ubuntu 16.04 con apache2 + php + mysql +phpmyadmin.

En la siguiente ruta entiendo que estan la configuracion de apache para los sitios  `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

En esta carpeta encuentro dos archivos 
el `000-default.conf` y `default-ssl.conf`
Entiendo que uno es el archivo de configuracion normal y el otro es el del ssl. el ssl ha sido activado a traves del  comando `sudo a2enmod ssl` y luego `sudo a2ensite default-ssl.conf`

El cerificado del dominio lo que configurado desde el amazon certificate y he creado un load balancer que se puede acceder desde el puerto http y https.

Llegados a este punto he ido al archivo `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` donde supongo que se ecuentra al configuracion prinpial del puerto *80.

Esto es lo que havia inicialmente sin tocarlo.

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
       
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

y luego he creado he añadido el siguiente codigo antes de la configuracion por defecto.

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName yourdomain.com
  Alias www.yourdomain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.yourdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  

</VirtualHost>
```

PD: tambien lo he provado borrando la configuración inicial y solo dejando el codigo de la redirección pero tampoco hace nada.

Os dejo el codigo del default-ssl.conf pro si os sirve de algo
haber si alguien me puede ayudar gracias de antemano.

```html
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

 </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: he provado las soluciones de este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection pero la mayoria me dan error 502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he solucionado el problema.
Como el dominio estava en un load balancer lo unico que tenido que hacer es configurar la redirección desde el load balancer de AWS del puerto 80 al 443